# Analysis of an improper integral

Tags: integration

For which $n \in \mathbb{N_*} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^n+1}$ is convergent? 
I know that if n is a even number, the integral converges, but I don't know how to proceed for odd n

Comment: If $n$ is odd then $\frac{1}{x^n+1}$ has a simple pole at $x=-1$, and a simple pole is a non-integrable singularity.

Comment: Unless you want to consider a Cauchy principal value, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JackDAurizio's comment, the integral diverges at all odd $n$, because it is unbounded at $x=-1$. But the integral converges for even $n$. However the positive half of the integral converges for all $n>1$

Comment: Not *because it is undefined*. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}(1+x^2)}$ is also undefined at zero and unbounded in a neigbourhood of the origin, but is belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.